# Converted Java Project to Maven Project, but missing a pom.xml?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

So in order to fix a NoClassDefFoundError problem, I needed to add this dependency to my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-m01</version>
</dependency>
```

so in order to have a pom.xml file, i converted my project to Maven.
Unfortunately, post-conversion, I don't seem to have a pom.xml

I tried going to the "Add Dependency" option in the Project->Maven path but I don't know what it's asking for a Group ID or Artifact ID so I don't think that's what I'm looking for.

All the helps I've read show the pom.xml just sitting inside their project explorer, i've attached a screenshot of what i see EDIT://just kidding i can't post images

Is there a pom.xml creation process? There's no options in the Maven toolbar that seem helpful here

Comment: You have run "Convert to Maven", right? Press F5 on your project in the project explorer (and furthermore check the physical folder in your hard disk for the pom.xml).

Comment: Yeah, that's how I converted the project to Maven. There is no pom.xml in my hard disk whatsoever.  Best I can figure, when I pressed the "Convert to Maven" button something went wrong and now the entire project is borked.

Comment: I just created an entirely new Maven project from scratch, redid my classes and that seemed to fix the problem, even though the proj is now titled "javax.ws.rs-api" for some reason i'm not gonna fiddle with it things seem to be working for now